# "No authentication challenges found" with twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to sign with twitter using `twitter4j`. 

my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
    static String consumerKey = "my_consumer_key";
    static String consumerSecretKey = "my_consumer_secret_key";
    static String accessToken = "my_access_token";
    static String accessSecretToken = "my_access__secret_token";
    User user;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecretKey)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecretToken);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

                System.out.println(twitter.getScreenName());
                     //getting error because of this line

            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
}
```

ERROR: When I am running this code it give me "**No authentication challenges found**" error.

 I have tried to solve this with the previous asked questions but get failed.

[image]

[link to same image(if you don't find it clear here)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/seto8y99r3r04y9/new.png?dl=0)

Can anybody tell me what mistake I am doing here?

**NOTE:** If I add `.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true)` to `cb` then I get a new error **neither user id/password nor OAuth consumer key/secret combination supplied.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
   final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecretKey)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecretToken);
        OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);
```